# How to enter an integer interactively in R

Tags: r

Dear all, I would want to enter an integer interactively into R and then capture it and use it in my code. I was trying it with the scan() function but it gave me errors!
This is what I have done:

```
#This is my question  
print("enter a positive integer")  
n <- scan()  
while(is.numeric(n) == F){  
  print("enter a positive integer")  
  n <- scan()  
}
```

Also, after the execution of the first line, I want the program to pause for me to enter n before it checks the while loop

```
#This part is not part of my question; after capturing n I would want to use it in a code like this.  
c <- ncol(d)  
r <- nrow(d)  
for(i in 1:c) {  
  d[n,i] <- 0  
}
```

many thanks to all who could be of help.
Isaac Owusu

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
n <- scan (what=integer(), nmax=1, quiet=T)
```

Answer (score 2):

This won't work while you're just pasting it into the terminal.  You actually have to source it from a file for scan() to work properly.  That's because when you paste it in then it immediately executes scan, then executes the carriage return after scan... etc.  So, save this in a file, 'myfile.R', and type

```
 source('myfile.R')
```

Once you get that far then you probably need to edit how you're using scan().  It fails with error if the wrong type is entered so you need a try() statement.  The way you're doing it integers that are entered will always be real.  Also, as has been posted in another answer, set nmax to 1.  The following will do what you want... although still a little oddly (as you'll see).

```
n <- NULL
while(is.numeric(n)==F){
  print("enter a positive integer")
  try(n <- scan (what=integer(), nmax=1), silent = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Hello John, many thanks! It is okay I can use it for what I want.

Comment: Hi John thanks a lot for your help. the first answers I was given worked.

Comment: They work but they don't follow the spirit of your initial intent which is to continue to work if someone enters something other than an integer.  That's the purpose of your conditional while loop.  This answer does just what you initially intended.

Comment: And BTW, if you did find one of the answers was 'the' answer for you then you should tag it as such.

Answer (score 1):

If on Windows you could use dialog boxes:

```
n <- winDialogString("enter a positive integer","")
```

It will always return character so you have to do necessary conversions and test.

E.g.:

```
isPositiveInteger<-FALSE
while(!isPositiveInteger) {
   n <- winDialogString("enter a positive integer","")
   isPositiveInteger <- grepl("^[1-9][0-9]*$", n)
}
n <- as.integer(n)
```

Comment: Hi Merek many thanks, I worked on the first answers that you and Joris gave and it worked finally with lots of struggles. This is also powerful. I pasted in the R console and it works. I am impressed by it. But I cannot find the "check box outline" that the faq talks about. So I dont know how I can let people know that the answer is ok.